# Facebook OpenGraph - issues with Activity Plugin

Tags: facebook, beta, facebook-opengraph

I've been able to post activities to my personal wall and timeline, but I don't seem to be able to get the Activity Plugin to go no matter how I call it.  I get a success when I call it, and have also been getting a success code from the command line CURL calls.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function postAttend()
{
    FB.api('/me/kaplangraph:attend' +
                '?class=http://samples.ogp.me/253928254644843','post',
                function(response) {
        if (!response || response.error) {
                alert('Error occured');
        } else {
            alert('Post was successful! Action ID: ' + response.id);
            }
    });
}
</script>
```

This I know is working.  I see them on my personal timeline.  I can't however pull them up in the Activity Plugin.  All of the following show up blank.  Am I missing something?

```
<fb:activity action="kaplangraph:attend"></fb:activity>
<fb:activity actions="kaplangraph:attend"></fb:activity>
<fb:activity actions="kaplangraph:attend" app_id=253477038023298></fb:activity>
<fb:activity app_id=253477038023298></fb:activity>
<fb:activity site_url="https://severe-winter-5145.herokuapp.com/"></fb:activity>
```

---

Thanks guys, I also posted to the FB developer group ... hoping to get an answer there.

I will post if I find anything, but I agree this is a bug and not a beta issue.  It says in the example that this will work for devs/admins/etc ... just not the world.  I am guessing somehow in the transition they killed the activity feed, as I am having trouble with others as well.

Answer (score 0):

The Facebook timeline and new open graph are still in beta.  I'm pretty sure it won't show up in the activity plugin until it is out of beta.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bug; Yes, they are in beta, but the tutorial makes no mention of the fb:activity not working. It is also unclear what parameters should be passed (action or actions).  I too have tried various ways of trying to get fb:activity to work, but for now I am waiting to see if there is any update to address this issue.